# Time Frequency bin

Tags: audio, frequency-domain, time-frequency, time-domain

I am doing research in audio signal processing for DOA estimation. I came across the term Time-Frequency bin. I have gone through several articles but none of them specify a TF bin rather it specifies only a frequency bin. The actual problem statement is "the coherence test is applied to the estimated co-variance matrix to identify rank 1 TF bins". Can anybody help me with the TF bins? Thanks in advance

Comment: For example google "Short time Fourier transform (STFT)"

Comment: my question is what does a TF bin mean? I understand that I have to perform STFT. but how do I divide the STFT into TF bins??